# WPF Touch UI limit image (or any element) to its parent

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, touch

I'm trying to develop an app for windows desktop that support touch screens
so i  want let user  zoom or move pics with touch
but my problem is with this code the picture will move around the windows not just in its parent (Canvas)

i want to limit picture (rectangle) in it's parent (canvas)

this is a sample code to move or zoom a rectangle :

xaml

```
   <Canvas Background="Green"  x:Name="_canvas"        
    ManipulationStarting="_canvas_ManipulationStarting"        
    ManipulationDelta="_canvas_ManipulationDelta" Margin="76,105,117,46">
        <Rectangle IsManipulationEnabled="True"  Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100"></Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
```

C#

```
          private void _canvas_ManipulationStarting(object sender,
                          ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ManipulationContainer = _canvas;
        e.Handled = true;
    }


    private void _canvas_ManipulationDelta(object sender,
                             ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {

        var element = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;

        var transformation = element.RenderTransform
                                             as MatrixTransform;
        var matrix = transformation == null ? Matrix.Identity :
                                       transformation.Matrix;

        matrix.ScaleAt(e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X,
                       e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y,
                       e.ManipulationOrigin.X,
                       e.ManipulationOrigin.Y);

        matrix.RotateAt(e.DeltaManipulation.Rotation,
                        e.ManipulationOrigin.X,
                        e.ManipulationOrigin.Y);

        matrix.Translate(e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X,
                         e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y);

        element.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Personally I'd just slap `MouseDragElementBehavior` from the Blend SDK on it with ConstrainToParentBounds=True and be done with it for the dragging bit.

Comment: thank you.  i try ZoomRotateBehavior in blend but same problem  !!!!!!! Witch parent window or canvas ? rectangle will limit in window Bounds not in parent (Canvas)

Comment: Sorry brother but I'm not familiar with "ZoomRotateBehavior" specifically. I was suggesting MouseDragElementBehavior, the zoom rotate stuff would have to be added to it.